# Sub-Enumerating Exercises and Alignment

Tags: enumerate, alignment

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{reflection}[2][Reflection]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{proposition}[2][Proposition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}%replace X with the appropriate number
\author{xxx\\ %replace with your name
xxx} %if necessary, replace with your course title

\maketitle

\begin{exercise}{1} Consider the PDE \[ u_{xx} - 2u_{xy} - 3u_{yy} = 0 \]
\end{exercise}

(i) Show that this PDE is hyperbolic. \\
%Note 1: The * tells LaTeX not to number the lines.  If you remove the *, be sure to remove it below, too.
%Note 2: Inside the align environment, you do not want to use $-signs.  The reason for this is that this is already a math environment. This is why we have to include \text{} around any text inside the align environment.
A second-order linear PDE in two variables is an equation of the form
\begin{align*}
Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_{x} + Eu_{y} + Fu = G,
\end{align*}

where $A, B, C, D, E, F,$ and $G$ can be constants or given functions of $x$ and $y$.

\end{document}
```

I want to be able to sub-enumerate my exercises as (i), (ii), (iii), etc. I then want to be able to write my solutions under the alignment of (i), (ii), etc, without the text being misaligned, as is the case in the above example (see image below). So all of the work related to exercise 1 falls neatly under the alignment of exercise 1, all of the work under the alignment of exercise 1 (i) neatly falls under the alignment of exercise 1 (i), etc.

Misalignment:

[image]

In the above image, `Exercise 1` should come first, then `(i)` should come second and fall under it in alignment. Then everything else should fall under `(i)` in alignment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? I used a real enumerated list, customised with package `enumitem`. Two possibilities: the first is the default, with a label right-aligned at the left margin of the list, the second is custom, with a label left-aligned in its box:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{reflection}[2][Reflection]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{proposition}[2][Proposition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}%replace X with the appropriate number
\author{xxx\\ %replace with your name
xxx} %if necessary, replace with your course title

\maketitle

\begin{exercise}{1} Consider the PDE \[ u_{xx} - 2u_{xy} - 3u_{yy} = 0 \]
\end{exercise}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), leftmargin=*, listparindent=0pt]
\item Show that this PDE is hyperbolic.

%Note 1: The * tells LaTeX not to number the lines. If you remove the *, be sure to remove it below, too.
%Note 2: Inside the align environment, you do not want to use $-signs. The reason for this is that this is already a math environment. This is why we have to include \text{} around any text inside the align environment.
A second-order linear PDE in two variables is an equation of the form
\begin{align*}
Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_{x} + Eu_{y} + Fu = G,
\end{align*}
where $A, B, C, D, E, F,$ and $G$ can be constants or given functions of $x$ and $y$.
\item
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{4ex}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), wide=2.5em, leftmargin=*, labelsep =-0.5em, listparindent=0pt]
\item Show that this PDE is hyperbolic.

%Note 1: The * tells LaTeX not to number the lines. If you remove the *, be sure to remove it below, too.
%Note 2: Inside the align environment, you do not want to use $-signs. The reason for this is that this is already a math environment. This is why we have to include \text{} around any text inside the align environment.
A second-order linear PDE in two variables is an equation of the form
\begin{align*}
Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_{x} + Eu_{y} + Fu = G,
\end{align*}
where $A, B, C, D, E, F,$ and $G$ can be constants or given functions of $x$ and $y$.
\item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's right, but I'd prefer to have a "staggered" alignment, where `(i)` falls slightly to the right of `Exercise 1`, and the text belonging to `(i)` falls slightly to the right of `(i)`. This makes it clear what text belongs under what header, and looks neater.

Comment: Do you mean `(i)` should vertically fall right after the dot  at the end of `Exercise 1.`???

Comment: Actually, you know what? Yours looks great. I'll use that instead. :D

Comment: Just take a look at two other possibilities. It's mainly a matter of personal taste…